# Exclude %~dp0 from line output in Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, hide

I am using robocopy in a batch file to copy everything from the directory where the batch file is run, to a destination folder like so:

```
robocopy %~dp0 "D:\Destination Folder" /E
```

In the command window, running the above outputs the full path to `%~dp0` like this:

```
C:\Folder\Another Folder\Batch File Runs From This Folder\This Folder Gets Copied\File.txt
```

I want the above output to exclude all of the folders leading up to the one where the batch file runs from, in other words exclude only `%~dp0` but retain the rest of the path so I can see what was copied, so it would end up only outputting this:

```
This Folder Gets Copied\File.txt
```

There are no options in Robocopy to do this and I have looked at things like `find.exe` and `findstr.exe` but they cannot exclude a portion of a line, those both only have a `/v` option that can hide lines containing the text you specify. That's no use since hiding `%~dp0` would hide the entire line and show no output.

I know if there's a way to do this I can just put a pipe at the end of the robocopy line with something like this, if such a thing like a "hidestring" application exists:

```
    robocopy %~dp0 "D:\Destination Folder" /E | hidestring %~dp0
```

That is just an example of how it might work, but like I said there is no such program "hidestring" - I wish there was!

Robocopy does have a `/LEV:n` option where `n` is the amount of directory levels deep you want to copy, but using that option has no bearing on the output, the full path including `%~dp0` is output.

Is there any way to do this?

Cheers folks.

**EDIT: @Jeff Zietlin, here's the full content of the command window:**

```
C:\Folder\ToBeCopied>robocopy C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\ "D:\Destination" /E /w:0 /r:0 /NP /NS /NDL /NJH /NJS /XX

            New File                    C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\Copy Current Directory.bat
            New File                    C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\Folder With File\File.txt

C:\Folder\ToBeCopied>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Where the above says this:

```
New File                    C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\Copy Current Directory.bat
New File                    C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\Folder With File\File.txt
```

I want it to just say this:

```
New File                    ToBeCopied\Copy Current Directory.bat
New File                    ToBeCopied\Folder With File\File.txt
```

In other words, do not display the current directory's path `C:\Folder` (aka `%~dp0`)

**EDIT 2:**

Jeff, if I run this in a batch file called **Copy Current Directory.bat**

```
pushd %~dp0
robocopy . "D:\Destination" /E
popd

pause
```

I get this in the command window:

```
C:\Folder\ToBeCopied>pushd C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\

C:\Folder\ToBeCopied>robocopy . "D:\Destination" /E

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 11 June 2021 17:13:45
   Source : C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\
     Dest : D:\Destination\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\
100%        New File                 167        Copy Current Directory.bat
          New Dir          1    C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\Folder With File\
100%        New File                   0        File.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         1         1         0         0         0
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :       167       167         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : 11 June 2021 17:13:45


C:\Folder\ToBeCopied>popd

C:\Folder\ToBeCopied>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: When I run `ROBOCOPY` on my box, I get quite a bit of formatted output. Are you just extracting the filename from the formatted output, or are there other options that you've eliminated as "irrelevant"?

Comment: Everything being output is relevant, apart from the text string `%~dp0` which I want to hide in the output. Since `%~dp0` ends before the sub-directories that get copied, if there's a way to hide just `%~dp0` it should leave the rest of the line displaying only the folders/files that are copied, not the entire path to them (which I don't care about or need to see, it's taking up a lot of space and making each line go off the edge of the command window).

Comment: As a test, create a folder with this batch file and ONE other file in it, then execute the batch file, and cutpaste the ENTIRE output of ROBOCOPY. My testing MAY have a way of addressing your issue, but I want to see EXACTLY what you're getting to compare with what I am getting before I propose a solution.

Comment: I can't paste that here, I will edit it into my question...

Comment: OK, I get a bunch of header and footer info as well, but I think my solution below will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `%~dp0` directly in the `ROBOCOPY` command, use

```
...
pushd %~dp0
ROBOCOPY . "D:\Destination Folder" /E
popd
...
```

When I do that, the filename lines from `ROBOCOPY` look like e.g.,

```
100%        New File                 800        Esperanto.ahk
100%        New File                 644        Sharp-S.ahk
100%        New File                 473        Sharp-S2.ahk
```

with no path, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Note: I wasn't aware of the extra parameters /NS, NDL, etc., so I didn't include them. The principal still applies; instead of using `%~dp0` directly in the `ROBOCOPY` command, use the pushd/robocopy ./popd sequence instead.

Comment: Sorry I can't get it to work. I tried it on 3 lines like you suggested, then tried a one-liner `pushd %~dp0 &
ROBOCOPY . "D:\Destination Folder" /E &
popd` but it doesn't work. I tried all combinations swapping the `%~dp0` for `.` and still always get the full path showing up. What gets me is there isn't a simple command line program to hide a string of text on a line, where it could just be run at the end of a line with a `|` character before it.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, when I use all of your additional switches, I get the same thing.

Comment: The key seems to be the `/NDL` switch. When I include that, I get your results. When I don't, I get an additional line at the top listing the directory, but the individual files have no path. If you can tolerate the additional line, just drop that switch; you likely won't even need the pushd/popd.

Comment: With only `/E` that's robocopy showing you a new file without the path, because robocopy shows files that way by default - above or below that line it also says `New Dir  1  C:\Folder\ToBeCopied\Folder With File` instead of the would-be solution:  `New Dir  1  ToBeCopied\Folder With File`

Comment: Where you had it displaying `Esperanto.ahk` above, that is cutting off any sub-directory that file might reside in :p I want to keep that, but only omit the current directory where this batch file is being run from. In the case of your `Esperanto.ahk` above, that's just robocopy itself removing the path (as per normal in robocopy). In other words adding the `pushd` command isn't going to affect that particular line since it's hiding the entire path (except the file) by default. This is so tough haha.

Comment: I wasn't working with multiple levels of files; everything I was testing with was at the same level. I don't think you can get the hybrid that you want; it's likely to be all-or-nothing, with each individual directory listed separately from the files in it.